# Search string returning indexes of all overlapping occurrences for multiple variable length Ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex, tuples, irb

I use the following code in Interactive Ruby (IRB) `$ irb` to search a string (i.e. `evidence`) and return an array of tuples (`guilty_term_indexes`). The second element of each tuple represents the character index in the `evidence` string where the first character of a `guilty_term` (stored in the first element of a tuple) has been found.

```
guilty_terms = [/danger/i, /hack/i, /ckdd/i]
regex_guilty_terms = Regexp.union(guilty_terms)
evidence = "hackddangerhackdanger"
guilty_terms_and_indexes = []
evidence.scan(regex_guilty_terms) do |index|
    guilty_term = Regexp.last_match.offset(0)[0]
    guilty_terms_and_indexes << [index, guilty_term]
end
p guilty_terms_and_indexes
```

I **expected** `guilty_terms_and_indexes` to return:

`[["hack", 0], ["ckdd", 2], ["danger", 5], ["hack", 11], ["ckdd", 13], ["danger", 15]]`

But instead it returns:

`[["hack", 0], ["danger", 5], ["hack", 11], ["danger", 15]]`

How can I get the **expected** results?

#### System

`$ ruby -v`
`ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matches can't overlap. Use zero-length assertions instead:

```
guilty_terms = [/danger/i, /hack/i, /ckdd/i]

# the positive lookahead is where the magic happens
regex_guilty_terms = /(?=(#{Regexp.union(guilty_terms)}))/
evidence = "hackddangerhackdanger"

# just a squeezin'
[].tap { |arr| evidence.scan(regex_guilty_terms) { |x| arr << [$1, $~.begin(1)] } }
# => [["hack", 0], ["ckdd", 2], ["danger", 5], ["hack", 11], ["danger", 15]]
```

The position 13 is not printed because it's not actually a match, so... not sure how you'd get the expected results :)

Comment: Very nice. (I was a few minutes behind you.) I would say part of the magic is how `scan` deals with capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a regex.

```
terms = %w| Danger hack ckdd |
  #=> ["Danger", "hack", "ckdd"]
evidence = "Hackddangerhackddanger"

down_terms = terms.map(&:downcase)
  #=> ["danger", "hack", "ckdd"] 
down_evidence = evidence.downcase
  #=> "hackddangerhackddanger" 

down_evidence.size.times.with_object([]) do |i,a|
  w = down_terms.find { |w| down_evidence[i..-1].start_with?(w) }
  a << [w,i] unless w.nil?
end
  # => [["hack",0], ["ckdd",2], ["danger",5], ["hack",11], ["ckdd",13], ["danger",16]]
```

Comment: The desired result suggests that `evidence` should have a "d" before  "danger" at the end of the string, so I added that. That also causes the index to be off by one (16 rather than 15) for the last match.